# Can't create included directory

Tags: mkdir

I'd like to create a new directory that looks like `/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4` but I can't.

If I create the directories one by one from the parent and new parent directories, everything works:

```bash
lm@debian:~$ sudo mkdir -v ./Pictures/Photos1/onbike2023/
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘./Pictures/Photos1/onbike2023/’: No such file or directory
lm@debian:~$ sudo mkdir -v ./Pictures/Photos1/
mkdir: created directory './Pictures/Photos1/'
lm@debian:~$ sudo mkdir -v ./Pictures/Photos1/onbike2023/
mkdir: created directory './Pictures/Photos1/onbike2023/'
lm@debian:~$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

`mkdir` by default won't create intermediate directories.  That is, if you want `mkdir foo/bar/baz` to succeed, `foo` and `foo/bar` had better already exist.

However, you can change this behavior by `mkdir -p foo/bar/baz`.  This option will cause any intermediate directories to be created if necessary.  It has the added benefit of not causing `mkdir` to exit with an error code if `foo/bar/baz` already exists.

Answer (score 1):

extract from `man mkdir`

```
-p, --parents
              no  error if existing, make parent directories as needed, with their file modes unaffected by
              any -m option.
```